# MongoDB: Filtrar los resultados del día en curso

Tags: mongodb

He creado un parámetro que me devuelve el día de hoy a las 00:00:00:

```
"fechaAhora": {"$toDate": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00", "date": "$$NOW"}}}
```

Si lo incluyo en la siguiente consulta:

```
var pipeline = 
[
    {
        "$match": 
        {
            "idDevice": 2353,
            "idSensor": 3,
            "data.inicio": {"$exists": true},
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": 
        {
            "fechaSD": {"$toDate": "$data.inicio"},
            "fechaAhora": {"$toDate": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00", "date": "$$NOW"}}}
        }
    },
    /*{
      "$match":
      {
          "fechaSD": {"$lt": "$fechaAhora"}
      }
    },*/
    {
        "$project":
        {
            "_id": 0,
            "fechaSD": "$fechaSD",
            "fechaAhora": "$fechaAhora"
        }
    },
]

db.sensorsData.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Me devuelve documentos tal que así:

```
{
  "fechaSD": "2022-02-05T23:00:00.000Z",
  "fechaAhora": "2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Si descomento esta etapa `$match`:

```
{
  "$match":
  {
      "fechaSD": {"$lt": "$fechaAhora"}
  }
},
```

Y vuelvo a ejecutar la consulta, esperaría que me devolviese todos los documentos anteriores al día de hoy, pero no devuelve ninguno. ¿Por qué puede ser?

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás usando incorrectamente el operador [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) en la etapa de agregación [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

Si leemos con detalle la documentación, esta indica lo siguiente:

> La etapa `$match` tiene el siguiente prototipo:
>
> ```js
> { $match: { <query> } }
> ```
>
> `$match` toma un documento (`<query>`) que especifica las condiciones de la consulta. La sintaxis de la consulta es idéntica a la sintaxis de consultas de lectura (`find`, `findOne`); por lo tanto `$match` no acepta expresiones puras de agregación (por ejemplo: `$lt`). En cambio, (si desea usar expresiones de agregación), utilice una expresión de consulta `$expr` para incluir cualquier expresión de agregación en una etapa `$match`.

Te preguntarás ¿porqué no toma el operador `$lt` si lo estoy usando como normalmente se usa para una consulta de lectura ([`$lt` query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/#mongodb-query-op.-lt))? La respuesta es simple, en una operación de consulta, MongoDB no interpreta `$fechaAhora` como un campo que has añadido en una etapa anterior. Para MongoDB, en una operación de consulta, `$fechaAhora` es una cadena de texto:

> Syntax: `{ field: { $lt: value } }`
>
> `$lt` selecciona los documentos donde el valor del campo (`field`) es menor que (`<`) el **valor** especificado.

(Negrillas añadidas por mi).

Y es que para MongoDB `value` es un valor y no una expresión.

Lo que quiero destacar es que existen dos tipos de operadores `$lt`, uno usado en consultas (`find`) y otro en etapas de agregación. En particular, la etapa `$match` utiliza un operador de consulta, cuya sintaxis no admite expresiones de agregación (`$fechaAhora` es una expresión de agregación).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Supongamos que deseo utilizar la fecha calculada en la etapa anterior (`fechaAhora`). Entonces deberías escribir tu etapa de agregación de la siguiente forma:

```js
{
  "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$lt": [
        "$fechaSD",
        "$fechaAhora"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Podemos ver el siguiente [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7UtW_iljrJI) donde he simplificado tu documento y he colocado 3 fechas iniciales, dos de ellas en un valor que a la fecha de esta respuesta son menores que la fecha actual y la tercera con un valor de 10 años a partir de la fecha actual. La consulta de agregación te devolverá sólo 2 documentos de los 3 que existen en la colección, tal como se espera. La consulta se vería así:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "fechaSD": {
        "$toDate": "$data.inicio"
      },
      "fechaAhora": {
        "$toDate": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00",
            "date": "$$NOW"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$lt": [
          "$fechaSD",
          "$fechaAhora"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Mejora**

Viendo lo que pretendes hacer y tomando en cuenta que ya conoces el poder de las variables de MongoDB ([`$$NOW`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.NOW)), no haría falta una etapa de [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/). Por ejemplo, la siguiente etapa `$match` utiliza directamente el valor de `data.inicio` para devolver los documentos que necesitas:

```js
{
  "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$lt": [
        {
          "$toDate": "$data.inicio"
        },
        "$$NOW"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Y es que al convertir `data.inicio` en una fecha con el operador de agregación [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/), MongoDB sabrá interpretar `$lt` con los valores que le estás pasando.

Podemos ver el siguiente [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ixpkIWECLId) donde he aplicado sólo la etapa `$match` a la misma colección anterior y el resultado es el mismo.

La consulta se vería así:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$lt": [
          {
            "$toDate": "$data.inicio"
          },
          "$$NOW"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Usando `$lt` como operación de consulta**

También podemos usar el operador de consulta [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) pero en vez de pasar una expresión de agregación (como `$fechaAhora` o `$$NOW`) usaremos un valor, y qué mejor valor que el de la fecha actual que podemos calcular con [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) de Javascript, al fin y al cabo, el motor de MongoDB corre sobre Javascript. El constructor de `Date`, devuelve la fecha actual del sistema cuando no se usa ningún argumento: `new Date()`, esto es el equivalente a `$$NOW`.

La etapa `$match` se podría ver de la siguiente forma:

```js
{
  "$match": {
    "fechaSD": {
      "$lt": new Date()
    }
  }
}
```

Claro, esto supone haber calculado el campo `$fechaSD` con la etapa `$addFields` tal como lo tenías antes. En el siguiente [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R0qfQsJr6ZW) puedes ver como funciona para la misma colección de ejemplo que he usado desde el inicio de la respuesta.

El código de la agregación completo podría verse así:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "fechaSD": {
        "$toDate": "$data.inicio"
      },
      "fechaAhora": {
        "$toDate": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "format": "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00",
            "date": "$$NOW"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "fechaSD": {
        "$lt": new Date()
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.